# TFS 2013 File not visible in Source Control Explorer

Tags: tfs

One of our developers is unable to see a file in TFS Source Control Explorer, yet myself and another developer can on our machines. The file is clearly there but for some reason it is not being displayed to this one developer, all other files in the folder are displayed correctly. He's set up as a project admin so it doesn't look like a permissions thing.

We're using VS 2013 Ultimate with TFS 2013 (Express). Anyone have any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: what extension of file it is? are you all on the same version of visual studio and operating system? since you are on tfs 2013, have you asked the developer to try browsing the file through internet explorer and verify the file is not visible from the browser as well. if it is visible, then may be clear the visual studio cache otherwise it has to be permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Have u looked at the project proj file to see if it's there? If not ,
unload the project and edit and add the reference of the file in the proj file.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is often related to the **Permission** . Please use [tf permission](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) command to list the related permission of that folder with the user.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be that the user has an odd workspace mapping.
For example given a source path $/project/folder1/folder2

A mapping like this
$/project/folder1/* c:\workspace

would show you all the files under folder1 and the directory name folder2 but files under folder2 would not show up in the workspace.